# Pandas: Delete Row if cell contains specific text

Tags: python, pandas

this code in pandas does not work. I want it to delete the row if the column contains any of the text/numbers provided Currently I can only get it to work if the cell matches the exact text being passed in my code .. as in it only deletes cells that say Fin* not Finance or Finly...

```
df2 = df[df.Team != 'Fin*']
```

Answer (score 19):

You can using `startswith`

```
df[~df.Team.str.startswith('Fin')]
```

Or

```
df[~df.Team.str.contains('Fin')]
```

Comment: @pes04 yw :-) happu coding

Comment: why does this need to be included: ~ before df in order to work?

Comment: @pes04 since you mention you need , not include , we just using ~ which mean unselect

Answer (score 11):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1,2,3,4], C=["abc","def","abcdef", "lmn"]))

df:

    A   C
0   1   abc
1   2   def
2   3   abcdef
3   4   lmn

df[df.C.str.contains("abc") == False]
```

OR as suggested by @RafaelC

```
df[~df.C.str.contains("abc")]
```

**Output:**

```
    A   C
1   2   def
3   4   lmn
```

Comment: `~df.C.str.contains("abc")`

Answer (score 5):

You need regular expressions for this operation. Here's a synthetic dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Team': ['Finance', 'Finally', 'Foo']})
```

Here's a dataframe that does not (`~`) have any Fin's:

```
df[~df.Team.str.match('Fin*')]
#  Team
#2  Foo
```

If you are sure that a string of interest always starts with Fin, you can use a "softer" method:

```
df[~df.Team.str.startswith('Fin')]
#  Team
#2  Foo
```

Comment: What would you do if you want to delete a row, via a specific column value for an integer - so instead of 'Fin*' as we used above we deleted in row with a column value of 3.5 and inversley how would we delete any row that did not contain a specific int. or string?

Answer (score 2):

The * is interpreted as [regex](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html). As that's not what you want, you can escape * by \

```
df2 = df[df.Team != 'Fin\*']
```

Or simply use

```
df2 = df[~dfTeam.str.contains('Fin')]
```