# Remove rows in that have any string from a set of strings pandas

Tags: pandas, set, string-comparison

I have a problem very similar to this one:

[Pandas: Delete Row if cell contains specific text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51182182/pandas-delete-row-if-cell-contains-specific-text)

But i need verify a list of strings, if each string is in each cell.

Ex.:

```
df = pd.read_excel(f'00\Partidas_01.xlsx')
Proibidas = 'blitz, Blitz, Rapid, rapid, Online, sim, simul, blindfold, consultation, random, odds, Odds, Chess960, NN'
proibited = set(list(Proibidas.split(', ')))

Partidas = df[~df['White'].str.contains(proibited)]
```

Any help will be very welcome!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972938/check-if-a-string-in-a-pandas-dataframe-column-is-in-a-list-of-strings

Comment: `Partidas = df[~df['White'].str.contains('|'.join(proibited))]`